# Holding down the alt key stops some keys from working

Tags: keyboard

If I hold down the (left) Alt key on my keyboard, a few - but not most - keys stop working. One of these is Tab, which means that it's difficult to Alt-Tab (not impossible - if I press Alt and then Tab in very quick succession it works).

I used "Key-Test" to check what's going on. I held Alt down and pressed every key multiple times. The white keys below are the ones that registered. As you can see, a handful of keys would not press while holding alt, without any very clear pattern. I have tried the keyboard on another computer and got the same result (at least, Alt-Tab did not work). This is a recently purchased (wireless) keyboard. I previously ordered one of these keyboards and had exactly this problem (again, I only tested Alt-Tab), so I sent it back. But now that the second keyboard has exactly the same issue I'm wondering if something else is going on.

[image: Keys that would/wouldn't press]

Comment: A keyboard is normally very basic. Can you try a simpler keyboard of a different make?

Answer (score 0):

Keys on a keyboard are arranged in a matrix, rows and columns, and scanned by firmware which checks for a connection between a row and a column to see that a key is pressed. Clearly this keyboard has some sort of problem with the left-Alt key that is preventing any other key in the same row (or perhaps column - terminology depends on how you hold your head I guess) from being detected when the key is pressed. As this has happened with two of the same model keyboards, it would seem to be a design or programming fault. I'd return for refund as defective, perhaps getting some other make / model keyboard to replace it.